# How To Disable The WordPress Theme Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know how to disable the plugin/theme editor in a specific WordPress site.

**My Question:** Is it possible to disable the the editor from a theme's `functions.php` file?

The idea is to have this turned off by default whenever my theme is active; however, once a few warnings are accepted, the editor can be re-enabled via the theme options page. (something that WordPress **should** be doing but, for whatever reason, does not.)

Beyond that, the particular theme in question is pretty advanced. Meaning that even someone who knows what they are doing could mess it up without realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend ended up answering this one for me, so for the googlers:

in `functions.php`:

```
if (in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('theme-editor.php'))) {
    if (get_option('theme_editor') != TRUE) {
        wp_die('<p>'.__('In order to edit this theme, you must first re-enable the theme editor via the <a href="'.theme::options_uri().'">Theme Options</a> page').'</p>');
    }
}
```

Just make sure you allow people to re-enable the theme editor via your Theme Options page. As silly as it sounds, some people actually really like it, and want it.

I ended up adding a very visible warning around re-enable button like so: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuky9zr3/)

Answer (score 9):

Nick, you can try with action to call a function in your functions.php to disable editor but wordpress did not provide any way to disable editor for theme only. If you use DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT than your plugin editor will also be disabled.

I feel you should try the below approach to disable editor from functions.php of your theme.

```
    function disable_mytheme_action() {
      define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', TRUE);
    }
    add_action('init','disable_mytheme_action');
```

you can also define some options and check in above function and control the disable file edit accordingly.

Comment: I can't give you the point because I ended up getting the answer from a friend IRL. But thanks, your answer would have gotten the job done, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found:

in functions.php or other theme setting code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'edit_menu');

function edit_menu()
{
    global $menu;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        // Is the user an admin?
        if (in_array('the_role_you_want_to_change', $user->roles)) {
            foreach ($menu as $key=>$value)
            {
                if ($value[2] == 'themes.php') unset ($menu[$key]);
            }
```

Answer (score -5):

open your wp-config.php file add code

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

OR try this extension

https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-theme-and-plugin-editor/

Comment: Next time, actually read the question, it will prevent the negative point.